# Regex for duplicate words in a string with one of them with a apostrophe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to create a regex for a requirement, a string is having duplicate words but in that duplicate words one is with a apostrophe.

For example:

```
EXCHANGE CORRESPONDENCE WITH BOLNO'S COUNSEL RE SCHEDULING INTERVIEW WITH DAVID BOLNO.
```

I am using this regex to validate by this way and splitting the string with that word.

```
var splitArray = this.narrative.split(new RegExp("\\b(" + this.misspelledWords[m] + ")\\b"))
```

But this regex string is considering BOLNO and BOLNO'S as single word.But I want to create my regex in such a way that it should consider BOLNO'S and BOLNO as different.

Can anyone help me this one.

Comment: Maybe `new RegExp("\\b(" + this.misspelledWords[m] + ")(?!['\\w])"` will be enough. You may  consider replacing ``\\b("`` with ``(?<![\\w'])("``, but it won't work in some browsers. There is an alternative for that, but more details are required then.

Comment: Did it help or if not, what is your exact use case? Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: It worked out for me. Thanks mate!!..

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: Did it work? Please check the solution and let know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
new RegExp("\\b(" + this.misspelledWords[m] + ")(?!['\\w])"
```

This also implies the `this.misspelledWords[m]` word cannot contain special chars.

The `(?!['\w])` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a `'` or a word char immediately on the right.